# I'd like to share two commands in discord bot js

Tags: discord, discord.js

used by default Slashcommand
But I want to use more commands
like this '!'

How can do that??
I hope your response

Answer (score 1):

Enable the `MessageContent` privileged intent in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), then you can add an on message listener

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) return; //return if the author is a bot
   if (message.content === '!ping') {
      console.log('Pong!') //execute command code here
   }
});
```

Comment: Agree, although you should use the `messageCreate` listener and not `message` as it's deprecated, and to add the `MessageContnet` intent in your Client builder.